# JSON to Groovy with JsonSlurper and unknown "string"

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I am writing a Grails/Groovy app and I have a JSON object with a "string" name (**grommet** and **widget**) inside the **params** member that can change. That is, next time it might be **acme** and **zoom**. Here is the JSON:

```
def jx = """{ 
    "job": "42",
    "params": {
        "grommet": {"name": "x", "data": "y"},
        "widget": { "name": "a", "data": "b"}
    } 
}"""
```

I am trying to figure out how to get the string **grommet** . Code so far:

```
def dalist = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jx)
println dalist.job     // Gives: 42
println dalist.params  // Gives: [grommet:[name:x, data:y], widget:[name:a, data:b]]
println dalist.params[0]  // Gives: null
```

Any idea how to get the string **grommet**? Iama going to keep hitting my head against a wall.

Comment: irb(main):001:0> rand(3) + 1
=> 1
the interwebs have spoken, answer 1 is picked. thanks all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `params` key on the JSON object is associated with a JSON object, not an array, so you cannot access it by index. JsonSlurper maps JSON objects to Groovy Maps, so you can access `params` by its keys, which are strings, e.g. `dalist.params.grommet`, which will give you the map `[name: 'x', data: 'y']`.

To access the keys on the `params` you can do `dalist.params.keySet()`, which will give you the list `['grommet', 'widget']`. If you are interested in just knowing `params` keys, that should do the trick. If you need to get the `'grommet'` string for some reason, you can do it by accessing the first element on that list, i.e. `dalist.params.keySet()[0]`, but i don't know why you would want to know that. And i'm not sure if it is guaranteed that the first key of that map will always be `'grommet'`, as JSON objects are unordered by the spec (from [json.org](http://json.org/): *An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs*), but, in turn, Groovy maps *are* ordered (the default implementation is LinkedHashMap)... so i would assume that the order is preserved when parsing JSON to the Groovy world, but i'd try not to rely on that particular behavior hehe.

Comment: I looked at the api again as I thought that it returned Object (doh!) and didn't see that it returned lists and maps. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's `Map` instance, try:

```
def params = dalist.params.entrySet() as List  // entrySet() returns Set, but it's easier to use it as a List
println params
println params.size()
println params[0]
println params[0].key
println params[0].value
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help you.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
def jx='{"job":"42","params":{"grommet":{"name":"x","data":"y"},"widget":{"name":"a","data":"b"}}}'

def dalist = new JsonSlurper().parseText( jx )

assert dalist.params.getClass().name == "java.util.HashMap";
assert dalist.params.size() == 2;

def keys = dalist.params.collect{ a, b -> a}; // returns "[grommet, widget]"
assert !!dalist.params.get( "grommet" ) == true
```

Comment: Thanks, this does what I was thinking I should be able to do. Now which one do I pick a check for? All three answers on the mark.

Comment: @rtfminc You could upvote all three and then pick one randomly.