# Grails, create domain object from json-string with has-many relation

Tags: json, parsing, grails, parameters

I'm trying to parse a grails parameter map to a Json String, and then back to a parameter map. (For saving html form entries with constraint-violations)

Everything is fine as long as there is no hasMany relationship in the parameter-map.

I'm using

```
fc.parameter = params as JSON
```

to save the params as JSON String.

Later I'm trying to rebuild the parameter map and create a new Domain-Object with it:

```
new Foo(JSON.parse(fc.parameter))
```

Everything is fine using only 1:1 relationships (states).

```
[states:2, listSize:50, name:TestFilter]
```

But when I try to rebuild a params-map with multi-select values (states)

```
[states:[1,2], listSize:50, name:TestFilter]
```

I'm getting this IllegalStateException:

```
Failed to convert property value of type org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray to required type java.util.Set for property states; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [de.gotosec.approve.State] for property states[0]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I tried to use this, but without success:

```
JSON.use("deep") {
   new Foo(JSON.parse(fc.parameter))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonSlurper instead of the converters.JSON of grails, it maps JSON objects to Groovy Maps. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060922/json-to-groovy-with-jsonslurper-and-unknown-string?rq=1) link also might help you.

Edit: Now, if the problem is binding the params map to your domain, you should try using bindData() method, like:

```
bindData(foo, params)
```

Note that this straightforward use is only if you're calling bindData inside a controller.

What seems to be happening in your case is that Grails is trying to bind a concrete type of List (ArrayList in the case of JsonSlurper and JSONArray in the case of converters.JSON) into a Set of properties (which is the default data structure for one-to-many associations). I would have to take a look at your code to confirm that. But, as you did substitute states: [1,2] for a method of your app, try another test to confirm this hypothesis. Change:

```
states:[1,2]
```

for

```
states:[1,2] as Set
```

If this is really the problem and not even **bindData()** works, take a look at [this](http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/02/15/rendering-json-in-grails-part-3-customise-your-json-with-object-marshallers/) for a harder way to make it work using object marshalling and converters.JSON. I don't know if it's practical for you to use it in your project, but it sure works nicely ;)

Comment: Hi, using JsonSlurper, leadst to this exception: Failed to convert property value of type java.util.ArrayList to required type java.util.Set for property states; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type     [java.lang.String] to required type [de.gotosec.approve.State] for property states[0]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found      --- why is the domain class required and not the id?

Comment: If you call the parse method from outside the object's constructor, you still get the same error? Or is it a object binding error?

Comment: its an object binding error. The parsing makes no problem. it returns a Hashmap where states is an ArrayList and 1 and 2 Strings.

Comment: If i replace the 'states:[1,2]' entry in the hashmap with State.getAll(map.get('states') as List<BigInteger>) everything is fine, but why do i have to do it. In the scaffolded save action the Domain Object is builded with the hash-map structure like 'states:[1,2]', why does it fail?

Comment: Neither bindData nor the Set casting works, casting to Set leads to the Exception: Failed to convert property value of type java.util.HashSet to required type java.util.Set for property states; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.Integer] to required type [de.gotosec.approve.State] for property states[0]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: What about the second link I posted ? I made a simple test with it and it worked ok for associations.